# Is there a way to prevent scalapb auto-generation for certain gRPC endpoints in a service?

Tags: scala, grpc, scalapb

We have a large gRPC service that contains many endpoints. When we try to add a new endpoint, compilation of the scala code generated by scalapb fails, because the `bindService` method in the service implementation is too large.

Because many endpoints in the service are not used in the scala code, we are looking for ways that scalapb can "ignore" certain gRPC endpoints in its auto-generation to avoid the method size limit (if possible).

Comment: could you share the full error message? is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.